# How can I set the mouse position?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, macos-carbon

I need to set the position of the mouse on the screen. In some other similar question, it was suggested to use `CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGDirectDisplayID display, CGPoint point)`, but I cannot figure out how to get the `CGDirectDisplayID`. Please tell me how to get the `CGDirectDisplayID` or a different method to set the mouse position.

Answer (score 7):

The real answer to this question is:

```
CGMainDisplayID()
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGMainDisplayID

```
CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), point);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I also tried some of the swift solutions after converting them to the new syntax, but they no longer seem to work.

Comment: What's the difference between `CGMainDisplayID()` and [`kCGDirectMainDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgdirectmaindisplay?language=objc)?

Comment: That’s the best solution, even for Swift developer. Thank you!

Comment: Surely that's "the real answer" only as soon as you can rid the world of second monitors?

Answer (score 4):

Try `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()`.  It doesn't require a display ID.

If you want a display ID, you can pick an element, using whatever criteria you like, from the array returned by `[NSScreen screens]`.  Invoke `-deviceDescription` on that `NSScreen` object.  From the dictionary that's returned, invoke `-objectForKey:` with the key `@"NSScreenNumber"`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
// coordinate at (10,10) on the screen
CGPoint pt;
pt.x = 10;
pt.y = 10;

CGEventRef moveEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
    NULL,               // NULL to create a new event
    kCGEventMouseMoved, // what type of event (move)
    pt,                 // screen coordinate for the event
    kCGMouseButtonLeft  // irrelevant for a move event
);

// post the event and cleanup
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, moveEvent);
CFRelease(moveEvent);
```

This will move the cursor to point (10,10) on screen (the upper left, next to the Apple menu).

Comment: Does not work. For some reason, it sets the x of the mouse correctly, but if I try to change the Y, it flickers between the top and bottom of the screen. Even if I use the current position of the mouse.

Comment: I just tried it with a variety of `x` and `y` values, and it moved to each of them. Are you posting any other events, or modifying this one, in some other fashion before posting it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Swift version, just for kicks:

```
let pt = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)
let moveEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(nil, .MouseMoved, pt, .Left)
CGEventPost(.CGSessionEventTap, moveEvent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version of the answer that helped me:

```
let pt = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)

let moveEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .mouseMoved, 
mouseCursorPosition: pt, mouseButton: .left)

moveEvent?.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in Swift 5:

```
let pt = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10)
        let moveEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .mouseMoved, mouseCursorPosition: pt, mouseButton: .left)
        moveEvent?.post(tap: .cgSessionEventTap);
```